# CiviRules - When does the 'Membership Payment Added' trigger fire?

Tags: civimember, civirules

I am using CiviCRM 5.13.4 and CiviRules 2.9.

I am using CiviRules to send an email to Contacts when they sign up for a Membership, but do so using 'Pay Later', to remind them how to pay etc.  The sign-up is via a Webform, but I'm not sure that matters.

The rule is set up to fire on 'Contribution Added', tests for the 'Pending' status and sends the Email - which all works OK.  The email uses a Template which contains (custom) tokens which fill in the Membership Type and Price into the text to be sent.

If I test this Template in a static environment, i.e. some time after the payment was made it works correctly, but when triggered by the Rule those Tokens just return empty.  I strongly suspect that this is because when the rule fires the Contribution record has been added to the database, but the Line Items which connect it to the Membership information have not yet been created.

When does the 'Membership Payment Added' trigger fire, and would it solve my problem?  Or is there another way?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too with event registrations, I added a five minute delay to the civirule and it seemed to clear up that issue.

Comment: Yes - I used that technique in another similar situation.  The only problem is that '5 minutes' actually means 'cron interval plus up to 5 minutes', and I would like the system to be more responsive than that from the end user's point of view.  It looks as if I may have to live with it though.  Tony

Answer (score 1):

The MembershipPayment Added trigger should fire on the post hook, which might in some cases (notably the memberships and cases) mean the data is not complete yet (see this issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/issues/21).

Comment: I certainly seem to be getting the problem described here.  Unless there is a workaround I haven't thought of?  Tony

Comment: Can you try if there is another entity you could trigger on that is fired when the data is complete?

Comment: I think the final link in the chain is the Line Item, which connects the Membership to the Contribution record, but there is no Trigger provided on Line Item.  If you can suggest anything else I would be happy to try it.  Tony.

Comment: LineItem is indeed not a trigger. I assume you have had a go with the Membership Payment? If that does not work then I have no solution until the mentioned issue 21 is fixed.

Comment: I have now tried triggering on Membership Payment, which fails.  Looking at the $triggerdata which is passed to the Action it has a Contact Id of 0, so any subsequent action on the Contact, such as sending them an email, throws an error.  Tony.

Comment: That is surely a sign of the data not being complete yet at the time of the post hook, so the mentioned issue 21 will be your saviour.

Comment: I look forward to Issue 21 being sorted.  Thank you, Tony

Comment: So you understand:  as CiviCooP we fund a Civirules sprint once a year. The next one is likely to be in the summer of 2020, and then this is one of  the issues on the list. Civirules is a community extension, anyone can fix bugs or solve issues. So it might be worth considering to either fix the issue yourself or fund the fix of this issue, either by us or any other CiviCRM partner? And obviously you are welcome to wait for next year's sprint :-)